# Pattern for Delegating Calls based on A Given State

Tags: javascript, node.js, design-patterns

I'm trying to think of a pattern I can use.

I want to be able to have a middleman module that takes in a kind of state of a game.  Given that state, call a certain method that resides in anotehr module.

What pattern could I use for this?

For example, I want to be able to take in a state of "computer always wins" and based on that state type, I'll call `someOtherModule.makeComputerMove()`.  In the future maybe we want to be able to set the game to a mode where the computer doesn't always win.  Well then we could send in a state of `"normal game"` or something like that which would just call `computerAlwaysWins.makeComputerMove()` from a different use case module such as `normalGame.makeComputerMove()`

get the idea?

I can't think of any patterns to provide such a thing...probably because I don't know a lot of them.

Comment: The state pattern sounds good enough? Google is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

You should use State pattern probably with combination of Observer.

```
public class GameStateContext {
    PlayerState Player {get;set; }
    // other properties that need to be shared
}

public interface IGameController {
    void GoToState(State state)
}

public interface IGameState {
   void Start();
   void Update();
}

public abstract class GameStateBase : IGameState {
    protected GameStateContext _context;
    protected IGameController _parent;

    public GameStateBase(GameStateContext context, IGameController parent) {
        this._context = context;
        this._parent = parent;    
    }

    public virtual void Start() {

    }

    public virtual void Update() {

    }
}

public class BonusLevelState : GameStateBase {
   public public MainMenuState (GameStateContext context, IGameController parent) : base (context, parent) {

   }

   public override void Update() {
       if(_context.Player.Health == 0) {
           _parent.GoToState(GameStates.GameOver);
       }
   }
}

public GameController : IGameController {
    public enum GameStates {
        BonusLevel,
        InitialState,
        ....
    }

    private IGameState currentState;

    public GameController() {
        // create diferent states
        ...
        currentState = GetState(GameStates.InitialState);
    }

    public void Update {
       currentState.Update();
    }

    public GoToState(State state) {
        currentState = GetState(state);
    }
}
```

I hope you catch an idea, good luck!